# Use a three by three

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What word does the image below represent?**

---

[image]

Comment: Just want to add, no knowledge required other than trivial. You just have to use the information from the title and then try to make sense of the image to find the word.

Comment: Is there any meaningful difference between the 2nd and 3rd almost-same images on each of rows 4, 5, 8 and 10?

Comment: @WeatherVane No, no difference. They're considered the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the word represented is

> DIRECTIONS

Reasoning

> Each square represents a direction. Single lines represent north, south, east, west while angles represent north-east, north-west, south-east, south-west.
>  Each line represents the drawing of a letter. The first square in each line represents how to get the start point from the middle of the letter and the subsequent squares represent the direction our pen needs to move in order to draw the letter - in order we have **D,I,R,E,C,T,I,O,N,S**.

Example

> If we take the first line as an example. Starting at the red dot in the picture below, go south-west (represented by the first square) to find the black dot - this is where we start drawing. The subsequent directions lead us all the way around the letter **D** and back to the black dot. The original red dot is the centre of the image.
>  [image]

Title

> We can visualise the drawing as moving between the centres of squares in a 3x3 grid where the initial (red) point is always in the centre square.

Comment: That's the correct answer, well done!